# Convert notebook file to Python file within DataSpell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jetbrains-ide, dataspell

I can't find a way on the internet to see the raw Python code from a notebook within DataSpell. Is there really no way to do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Perhaps you wish to strip a notebook? https://pypi.org/project/nbstripout-fast

Comment: You mean an option like Jupyter notebook: File-> Download as -> Python (.py) ? I Couldn't find it in DataSpell either.

Comment: @JuanRojas You can click on the button with a world icon on the top right of the notebook (when opened in pycharm/dataspell) and from the jupyther notebook on the web editor, you can download it a .py file. But I was wondering when I ask this question if there was a quickest way to vie the python code corresponding to which of the notebook without having to download.